# Trapped in reviewing: "I'm done" vs "No action needed"

Tags: bug, comments, review

A question I'm reviewing includes an "Update" section that provides an answer. I don't notice that it provides an answer.

1. I select *"No action needed"*.
2. Then I notice the answer embedded in the question.  I add a comment that suggests moving that solution to an answer, and mentions that accepting your own answer is fine.
3. I'm prevented from selecting *"I'm done"*. *Why?*
4. I notice that there's a useful tag to add. I click `Edit` and add the tag.
5. Now I can select *"I'm done"*.   I do so.  *Why wasn't this possible after adding a comment?*
6. Now I see that my comment is *gone*.  I have to type it again.

Why all this back-&-forth mic-mac?  The old UI was more useful, IMO - simpler, clearer, more flexible, and certainly less in-your-face. (Perhaps this is what comes of trying to impose modal behavior where it doesn't really belong.)

Perhaps this bug can be fixed, at least?

Comment: That's what happens when trying to fix things that are not broken: you end up breaking something and cause way more harm than good. I'd be glad to see the old UI back in this case.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard The old UI would have been worse in this case. Once clicking on "No Action Needed", it would have been submitted immediately, whereas with the current UI, it would be at least *technically, somewhat* possible to change it before submitting. That said, I've [written a user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/8892/stack-exchange-one-click-reviews) that replicates the old behavior for the review UI (submitting immediately on click).

Comment: @Sonic well "No Action Needed" is an action: it means the post is fine, nothing needs review, and I never expected it to let me keep reviewing the post after clicking it. So I disagree it's worse.